My plugins are not updating and they are showing error messages
I am trying to update Elementor, Plugin Essential Addins For Elementor and Starter templates but I get three errors:
An error occurred while updating Elementor:
Could not create directory.
/home/mdjebhjv/domains/taiservicescic.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/upgrade/elementor.3.21.8


An error occurred while updating Essential Add-ons for Elementor:
Could not create directory.
/home/mdjebhjv/domains/taiservicescic.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/upgrade/essential-addons-for-elementor-lite.5.9.24

And an error occurred while updating Starter Templates:
Could not create directory.

/home/mdjebhjv/domains/taiservicescic.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/upgrade/astra-sites.4.3.2

I also get an error when trying to update WordPress.
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-6.5.4-partial-3.zip…

Download failed.: The checksum of the file (d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e)
does not match the expected checksum value (0f4e93ba0830a195d3917e86274477ce).

Installation failed.

I have enough disk space and a tmp file, but I don't have a clue on what else I need to do.
